# Изменить заголовок окна

Tags: ассемблер, дизассемблирование

Имеется приложение , и у него есть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Требуется исправить опечатку в заголовке окна. Я правильно понимаю , что необходимо найти в дизассемблированном коде setwindowtext , чтобы уже как-то через него исправить ошибку , то есть symple изменить на simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Запустите любой HEX редактор
- Откройте в нем Ваш exe-файл
- Найдите там строку `Symple editor` (она может быть в двухбайтовой UTF-16), поэтому нужно искать последовательность байт `53 79 6D 70 6C` или `53 00 79 00 6D 00 70 00 6C`
- Замените один символ
- Сохраните файл и проверьте работоспособность

Comment: изменил , теперь не запускается программа

Comment: @Elvin Вы в том месте изменили? Вы увидели всю строку?